# Adding a field for uploading multiple images in ver 6.0 rc.3 of redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js, redux-form

I am experimenting the `redux-form v6.0.0 rc.3` and trying to add a field for uploading multiple images.

**Idea 1: add a field with type="file"**

```
attachImages(images) {
        console.info('images received: ', images);
    }

<Field
                      name="pics"
                      component={renderInput}
                      placeholder="Pictures"
                      onDrop={this.attachImages}
                      type="file" />
```

**Idea 2: Using the third-party Dropzone component:**

```
onDrop(files, evt) {
        console.log('received files: ', files);
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

<Dropzone
                     onDrop={ this.dropFile }
                 >
                   <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                 </Dropzone>
```

I've tried both ideas, but the first one cannot trigger the onDrop function at all, and the second idea seems more promising, however, I don't know how to add a field with the API for ver 6.0.0 rc.3. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much struggling, I made my second idea work by modifying the `onDrop` callback for the `Dropzone` component a little bit. The modification includes using the `dispatch` function of the reduxForm wrapper component with the action type redux-form/CHANGE.

```
onDrop(files, evt) {
        console.log('received files: ', files);
        evt.preventDefault();
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'redux-form/CHANGE',
            field: 'images',
            value: files, // files is an array of File
        });
    }
```

Then in the reducer, I watch for the action type `redux-form/CHANGE` and extract the files for uploading. This may be a little bit too hacky, but it works with the current ver 6 RC3 API.

Comment: Accepted until someone comes up with a better solution. hopefully this will benefit someone someday landing on this page from search engines

Comment: Did you ever find a solution other than the one above?